# How to call function iside a module dynamically?

Tags: python

How to call a function inside a (code of a) module dynamically?

For example:

```
class Class1(object):
    pass

class Class2(object):
    pass

# here I want to either instantiate object dynamically or dynamically pass 
# a Class1 or Class2 object to some other method/class inside this module code
```

Comment: You're going to have to be a bit more specific. Some more coded examples, perhaps?

Comment: What have you tried so far? In Python you can pass classes around like any other object.

Comment: Python is weakly typed.  There is nothing to restrict you from just passing an object of either type to any function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
>>> class Class1(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> class Class2(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> def foo(cls):
...     print cls
... 
>>> import random
>>> classes = {'Class1': Class1, 'Class2': Class2}
>>> dynamic_class = classes['Class%d' % random.randint(1, 2)]
>>> foo(dynamic_class())
<__main__.Class1 object at 0x10b44ab50>
```

Comment: I think this example would be a little more constructive if you explicitly created the dictionary that is being returned by `locals()`.

Comment: Agreed.  (+1) for your efforts (and nice example)

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you mean you want to access the classes by name.

If the class you want is in the same module, try `globals()[classname]()` to instantiate the class. If it's in another module, try `vars(module)[classname]()` or `getattr(module, classname)()`.

(`classname` is a string containing the name of the class; `module` is a reference to the module, not a string.)

Comment: I've never seen `vars(module)[classname]()`.  Is there a reason to prefer this over `getattr`?  (Or is this another Tomato, tomato thing?)

Comment: I kind of like `vars(modules)` because it's analogous with `globals()`—you get back a dictionary with either so the rest is the same. Otherwise, matter of taste, I guess.